# What is the difference in the following two groupby() statement in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am doing the Data Science course from Coursera.

This question is regarding groupby() method. I tried the examples shared by the tutor and then made a changing of my own. I thought that both versions (the original and the varied) should have the same result, but it was not. The only difference I made is removing the **set_index('STNAME')** which I thought shouldn't matter since there is only one single index and since I have **groupby(level=0)** this should be all. What is wrong which I am not understanding about **set_index(..)** here?

**Original**

```
df.set_index('STNAME').groupby(level=0)['POPESTIMATE2010','POPESTIMATE2011'].agg({'avg': np.average, 'sum': np.sum})
```

**Modified**

```
df.groupby(level=0)['POPESTIMATE2010','POPESTIMATE2011'].agg({'avg': np.average, 'sum': np.sum})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one, you are `groupby` `STNAME` which is your original index .

For the second one your are `groupby` the range index which make each group size is 1

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3,4,5]},index=[1,1,2,2,2])
df.groupby(level=0).sum()
    A
1   3
2  12
df.reset_index().groupby(level=0).sum()
   index  A
0      1  1
1      1  2
2      2  3
3      2  4
4      2  5
```